Is it halal for my mom to travel without a male mahram in this case?
My mom is currently divorced and has no male mahrams by her side except her brothers who live far from her. She lives with my younger sister back home and I am in a different country, does this mean she can't travel for example by car since she has no mahram to be with in the car?
